# Is a demo available for the Mac version of Arkham Asylum?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

Now that Arkham Asylum has been released for the Mac, is there a demo available? I know there's a [demo of the Windows version](http://www.joystiq.com/game/batman-arkham-asylum/download/batman-arkham-asylum-demo/).

Answer (score 4):

A demo is in the works, but has not yet been released. On [the Media page of the developer's website](http://www.feralinteractive.com/?game=bmaa&subsection=media), there is a "Demo" link, which currently brings up the message "Coming Soon..."

I will update this answer once the demo has been released.